# My leopard gecko won’t shed his dead skin off!

Tags: leopard-geckos, shedding

My leopard gecko, Charlie, is 6 months old. This is his second shed since I got him! And it took him over 24 hours. He won’t even try to get the shed off of him! He has it on his head, and his entire body is covered, and is starting to peel wrong, and he isn’t touching it! Should I help him? I really hope nothing too bad is wrong with him, he is basically the love of my life. Can anyone please help me?